# What's the difference between Allow Notifications being on vs. off if all the sub options are disabled?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

If I have everything switched off for an app in the Notifications menu of the Settings app (sounds, alerts, badges, etc.), what is the difference between the Allow Notifications switch being on or off?  Are there still some silent notifications coming thru?

Comment: Test it: switch everything off for an app that uses push, generate some notifications for yourself, switch things on and see if they show up in the notification center retroactively. Disallow Notifications and repeat.

Comment: I did test it, i don't see any difference.

Comment: Sounds like there's not much difference then. Maybe the difference is that from the app's perspective it has permission from the user to issue notifications even if they don't show up. I haven't used remote notifications but I'm guessing there's a way to programmatically check that permission. If so, disabling the sub options is perhaps the only way to disable notifications for an app that wants to force them upon you.